# How Lua deal with the stack?

Tags: lua

I'm trying Lua and want to know how lua_State working
code and result:

state.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lua/src/lua.h"
#include "lua/src/lauxlib.h"
static void stackDump(lua_State *L){
    int i;
    int top = lua_gettop(L);
    for(i = 1; i<= top; i++) {
        int t = lua_type(L, i);
        switch(t){
        case LUA_TSTRING:
            printf("'%s'", lua_tostring(L, i));
            break;
        case LUA_TBOOLEAN:
            printf(lua_toboolean(L, i) ?"true":"false");
            break;
        case LUA_TNUMBER:
            printf("%g", lua_tonumber(L, i));
            break;
        default:
            printf("%s", lua_typename(L, t));
            break;
        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

static int divide(struct lua_State *L){

    double a = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
    double b = lua_tonumber(L, 2);
    printf("%p\n", L);

    stackDump(L);

    int quot = (int)a / (int)b;
    int rem = (int)a % (int)b;

    lua_pushnumber(L, quot);
    lua_pushnumber(L, rem);

    stackDump(L);
    printf("---end div---\n");

    return 2;
}

int main(void){
    struct lua_State *L = lua_open();
    lua_pushboolean(L, 1);
    lua_pushnumber(L, 10);
    lua_pushnil(L);
    lua_pushstring(L, "hello");

    printf("%p\n", L);

    stackDump(L);

    lua_register(L, "div", divide);
    luaL_dofile(L, "div.lua");

    stackDump(L);
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

div.lua
    `local c = div(20, 10)`

> 0x100c009e0
>   true 10 nil 'hello'
>   ---start div---
>   0x100c009e0
>   20 10
>   20 10 2 0
>   ---end div---
>   true 10 nil 'hello'

I see `lua_State` in `divide` is the same with the `main` one, but they have different data in stack, How this be done ?

I know the best way to understand this is to read source code of Lua , maybe you can tell me where to find the right place.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking *why* it is that they have different information on the stack, or what exactly?

Comment: Yes, just like you said.(same lua_State but hold different data). sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: That didn't clear things up. Are you asking *how* it gets different data (ie: what Lua's doing to the `lua_State` behind the scenes that gives it new data), or *why* the stack has different data? Or are you asking something else entirely?

Comment: `how it gets different data` , this' the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets different data the same way *anything* gets different data: code changes the data inside of the object.

```
struct Object
{
  int val;
};

void more_stuff(Object *the_data)
{
  //the_data->val has 5 in it now.
}

void do_stuff(Object *the_data)
{
  int old_val = the_data->val;
  the_data->val = 5;
  more_stuff(the_data);
  the_data->val = old_val;
}

int main()
{
  Object my_data;
  my_data.val = 1;

  //my_data.val has 1.
  do_stuff(&my_data);
  //my_data.val still has 1.
}
```

Comment: I can imagine the logic ..... maybe it's just simple . I'll read the Lua code , thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Think of lua_State as containing the Lua stack, as well as indices delimiting the current visible part of the stack. When you invoke a Lua function, it may look like you have a new stack, but really only the indices have changed. That's the simplified version.

`lua_State` is defined in `lstate.h`. I've pulled out the relevant parts for you. `stack` is the beginning of the big Lua stack containing everything. `base` is the beginning of the stack for the current function. This is what your function sees as "the stack" when it is executing.

```
struct lua_State {
  /* ... */
  StkId top;  /* first free slot in the stack */
  StkId base;  /* base of current function */
  /* ... */
  StkId stack_last;  /* last free slot in the stack */
  StkId stack;  /* stack base */
  /* ... */
};
```

*Programming in Lua, 2nd Edition* discusses Lua states in chapter 30: Threads and States. You'll find some good information there. For example, `lua_State` not only represents a Lua state, but also a thread within that state. Furthermore, all threads have their own stack.

Answer (score 0):

When Lua calls a registered C function, it gives it a new stack frame.